# How do I convert an entity from one type to another in ColdFusion ORM?

Tags: orm, coldfusion, type-conversion, coldfusion-9

Let's say I have three entities, `Company`, `StandardCompany`, and `CompanyTemplate`, where `Company` is the base class for the other two:

```
                Company
                  /\
                 /  \
                /    \
  StandardCompany    CompanyTemplate
```

And the component mappings:

```
component name="Company" mappedSuperClass="true"
{
    property name="Name";
}

component name="StandardCompany" persistent="true" extends="Company"
{
    property name="Owner";
}

component name="CompanyTemplate" persistent="true" extends="Company"
{
    property name="UsageCount";
}
```

The user should have the ability to convert any `StandardCompany` to a `CompanyTemplate` and back again. I know I can create a new `CompanyTemplate` whenever the user wants to convert a `StandardCompany`:

```
function ConvertToTemplate(StandardCompany company)
{
    var template = EntityNew("CompanyTemplate");
    // copy all properties from company to template
    EntitySave(template);
}
```

But this will create a new record and break any bookmarks to the old company. I'd like to be able to just convert it to a `CompanyTemplate` without creating any new records. I'm using table-per-hierarchy mapping.

How can I accomplish this by just modifying the **type** of the `Company`, without having to create a new record for it?

Comment: Can you explain what a company template is? Because it doesnt seem like a company template "is a" company, so shouldnt really be inherited from the company superclass. Anyway, im pretty sure you cant do type conversions in cf9 orm, but i dont think you should need to if you build your heirachy differently. For example, you could have a one to many relationship between standardCompany, and companyTemplate. Or have an isTemplate field in the standardCompany class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I accomplish this by just modifying the type of the Company,
>   without having to create a new record for it?

You cannot.  You're using mappedSuperClass, meaning you're storing `StandardCompany` and `CompanyTemplate` in seperate table.

If you use [**Table per subclass with discriminator**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WS027D3772-2E98-4d5b-8800-054A62EBF8D9.html#WS9CAFDC25-4316-4d76-819A-FEBA45CC870B), you can change the value of the `discriminatorColumn` then you can modify the type "without having to create a new record".